# How to choose a integer number with the function random in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list, random

I have a list of numbers and I want to pick a random number with random() from that list so that I can use it in a loop function but python doesn't let me do that even when I write that the random number chosen is an integer.

Comment: Put your code + error so we can improve it

Comment: So what went wrong when you used [`choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice)?

Answer (score 3):

You should start by importing **random**.

So it should like something like this e.g.

```
import random

myList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
print(random.choice(myList))
```

Then it will print out a random number from your list.